# Where is Runnable used apart from passing it to Thread's constructor?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, sonarqube, runnable

I am trying to understand the Sonar rule [squid:S1217](https://sonar43.spring.io/rules/show/squid:S1217?modal=true&layout=false) wherein it is mentioned that it is a bad practice to call Thread.run() and Runnable.run() methods. I want to know the scenarios where Runnable.run() can be used.

Comment: While it is indeed a bad practice to call `Thread.run()`, I do not agree to naming `Runnable.run()` in the same sentence. After all, `Runnable` is an ordinary interface and its `run()` method an ordinary method. And, if you are going to implement an `Executor`, you *have* to invoke that method…

Comment: this is really confusing, in you question you say that you want to better understand the sonar's violation and you accept an answer that only gives best practice so for me it is even out of subject, please at least rewrite your question to be consistent with the answer that you accepted

Comment: The accepted answer provides an instance where Runnable.run() is used apart from the Thread's constructor and that is what I enquired about.

Comment: It is even worse than I thought you have 2 questions in one, so you really need to rewrite your question

Comment: `Runnable` is the standard abstraction for representing a _potentially asynchronous task_.  It is used by both `Thread` (which you should probably avoid using), by task management frameworks like `Executor` (which you should prefer over `Thread`), and anywhere an API wants to represent a standalone task (such as a completion handler.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than instantiating Threads directly, you should rely on ExecutorServices (see [Executor Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) in the Java tutorial). These take Runnables as parameters [in some of their methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Example:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
});

// alternative Java 8 lambda syntax:
executorService.execute(() -> System.out.println("Asynchronous task"));

executorService.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call Thread.run() or Runnable.run() directly it will act as a simple method, hence there is no multi-threading behavior in your program. And this methods are internally called by start() method which is responsible for multi-threading.